# Why won't the Sass property map-get work?

Tags: css, sass

I have a map of font weights. I then try to access one of the keys using `map-get()` however when I save my scss file and switch to my css. I see the property is not assigned. Furthermore, When I open the developer tools I can see the exclamation mark next to the property value. It says "invalid property value". Also I have a live watch extension on my scss files. In the output I'm reading. "Error: argument `$map` of `map-get($map, $key)` must be a map". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$theme-color: green;
$text-color: white;
$font-weights: (
    "regular", 400,
    "medium", 500,
    "large", 100
);

body {
    background-color: $theme-color;
    color: $text-color; 
    font-weight: map-get($font-weights, large);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained on the reference site, maps define with **`:`** as the following code:

```
$font-weights: (
    "regular": 400,
    "medium": 500,
    "large": 100
);
```

More information:
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps#look-up-a-value